In which file format does Network Monitor Pro app on Android export it's config file?
I had imported a Profile in Tasker that sorts the files in my Download folder based on the file extension.
But there's a file from Network Monitor Pro's export and Google Files app doesn't show any file extension for it.
Solid Explorer on Android says it's 'text/plain'
Tried putting the file on my Windows computer and it displays the file type as 'FILE' for it.
So which file extension does it have so that Tasker can match it up?

I think you have answered the question by yourself: Network Monitor Pro's exported config file doesn't have any extension, but the content is in plain text.
As mentioned in the question, Windows will show the file type simply as "File" when there is no file extension.
Solid Explorer possibly interprets the file type based on its content. However, there are many file extensions that are in plain text. On the other hand, files without extensions can have any type of content either.

Actually had emailed the dev about it. He assured that we can use any file extension to it as the contents of the file are encrypted
